# How do I change cassandra.yaml when building an environment with Terraform?

Tags: scalardb, scalardl

I will build the environment using the following Terraform.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalar-terraform

I want to fix the `cassandra.yaml` placed in a Cassandra instance with Terraform.
How do I change the Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually update the cassandra.yaml.j2 of the Cassandra module.

`provision/ansible/playbooks/roles/cassandra/templates/cassandra.yaml.j2`

It is not very recommended since you need to maintain the module itself if you do this.